# How to manage multiple conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume a very simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'Col1': ['Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Cyan'], 'Col2': ['Cyan', 'Magenta', 'Magenta'], 'ColFin': ['', '', '']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df['ColFin'] = np.where(((df['Col1'] == 'Yellow') & (df['Col2'] == 'Cyan')), 'Green', '')
df
```

How can I manage multiple conditions so that my final df also contains orange and purple for the 2 remaining rows of ColFin?

Basically, what I am trying to achieve on a more complex set of data is the equivalent of a Select Case in VBA.

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: look at `np.select` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'and' instead of '&' to compare multiple conditions.

So it could be changed as:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'Col1': ['Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Cyan'], 'Col2': ['Cyan', 'Magenta', 'Magenta'], 'ColFin': ['', '', '']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df['ColFin'] = np.where((df['Col1'] == 'Yellow' and df['Col2'] == 'Cyan'), 'Green', ''
df
```

Comment: Thanks NiKS. I note that but that doesn't solve my issue. In my example here, how would you cold the fact that if Col1 = Yellow and Col2 = Magenta then ColFin = Orange but also that if Col1 = Cyan and Col2 = Magenta then ColFin = Purple? Cheers